# Why is my random binary data generated in JavaScript highly compressible?

Tags: javascript

My Goal is to generate Incompressible data in Javascript like /dev/urandom

I used the following command from my Mac and i got 31.5 Mb of data that is not compressible using ZIP or RAR.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt bs=1048576 count=30
```

But when i try to produce Incompressible data in Javascript like /dev/urandom

It is very easy to compress in WinRAR. WinRAR compressed to less than 1Mb.
In Zip it is getting compressed to 30Mb

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>How to generate Incompressible data in Javascript like /dev/urandom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
var ulDataSize = 30;  //Mb
var mData = new Float64Array(131072);
var n = mData.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mData[i] = Math.random()*9;
        }
var uploadData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ulDataSize; i++) uploadData.push(mData);
        uploadData = new Blob(uploadData, { type: "application/octet-stream" });

function download(text, name, type) {
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  //var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(uploadData);
  a.download = name;
}

    </script>


<a href="" id="a">click here to Download Incompressible data</a>
<button onclick="download('file text', 'Incompressibledata.txt', 'text/plain')"> Generate Data</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, try switching to uint8array and use all values instead.

Comment: Besides what's the rationale behind reusing that same data 30 times? That way it's clearly compressible...

Comment: Becaus eit's not completely random. As @user202729 pointed out, you're repeating a block of random data 30 times which is not random enough

Comment: It's not the same data. See Math.random inside the forloop.

Comment: Please try the code and use Zip & RAR to compress it.

Comment: @user3642342 - `for (var i = 0; i < ulDataSize; i++) uploadData.push(mData);` clearly reuses the same data `ulDataSize` times, as the comments above said.

Comment: Any particular reason you went for `Math.random` for your random number generation? If you want random data, perhaps `crypto.getRandomValues` would suit you better?

Comment: More browser support, that is the only reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact you're repeating the same data 30 times (which is inherently non-random), I don't think `Math.random() * 9` produces values across the full range of bit patterns that an element in a `Float64Array` can hold (though my binary floating point knowledge isn't quite up to supporting that doubt with data), which means more bit patterns will be repeated, reducing the randomness.

To be sure, I'd probably use a `Uint8Array` with values in the full range 0 to 255, since then I'm sure I'm using all bit patterns; something like this:

```
function download(name) {
    const blocks = Array.from(
        {length: 30},
        () => Uint8Array.from(
            {length: 1024 * 1024},
            () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
        )
    );
    const blob = new Blob(blocks, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    const a = document.getElementById("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = name;
}
```

Note that I've removed the unused `name` and `type` parameters.

When I use that, `gzip` (the tool I have handy) doesn't reduce the size of the resulting file (it goes from 31,457,280 bytes to 31,462,121 bytes).

That's a lot of calls to `Math.random()`, but we're basically guaranteed that we fully explore the available bit patterns. You might be able to reduce the number of calls by using a `Uint16Array` or a `Uint32Array`. For instance:

```
const blockSize = (1024 * 1024) / 4;
const blocks = Array.from(
    {length: 30},
    () => Uint32Array.from(
        {length: blockSize},
        () => Math.random() * 4294967296
    )
);
```

For me, `gzip` still couldn't do anything with it (same result as above), but it took just over a quarter of the time to generate.

Using a `Float64Array` did *not* work (for me), apparently `Math.random` doesn't explore the full range of bit patterns possible in a 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point number and/or the format has (probably small) unused ranges. So 32-bit ints may be the best compromise.

Comment: it is Working, ZIP and ZAR not make any difference. Awesome.

Comment: But it is CPU intensive. Taking a second or TWO in my i7 MBP. Can we make it little more CPU Efficient?. Still it's Awesome!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3642342 - Well, it's 30M calls to `Math.random`, not a great shock if that's taking a moment. Looks like you can call `Math.random` less by using a `Uint32Array` (see update). Still worked for me, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Yes, it is 2x faster now.

Comment: @user3642342 - Huh, I got not quite 4x at my end, but implementations vary. :-)